# php5apache2_4.dll not found error

Tags: php, apache, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to integrate php on Apache. Following is the versions I'm using

```
Apache 2.4 (httpd-2.0.64-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8o)
PHP (php-5.5.0-Win32-VC11-x64.zip)
```

I'm setting this on a `64 bit` `windows 7` machine. I have made the configurations as per [this](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml), but I'm getting the following error even though I have place the `dll` in the specified folder.

> Cannot load C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified
>   module could not be found.

The `httpd.conf` line entry is this

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

Is there any version compatible issues?

Comment: Yes, there is a version incompatibility issue here. You're trying to use Apache 2.0, which is ancient, with a copy of PHP for Apache 2.4.

Comment: I tried with apache 2.4 64 bit and php 5.5, still getting the same error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right Marty, they work only if both are either 32bit or 64 bit. I used [XAMPP- Apache's distributed installation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 26):

The only way I've been able to get PHP (5.5) to work with Apache (2.4) on Windows (7 and 8) is to **make sure Apache and PHP are both either 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) and that Apache and PHP are both Thread Safe (TS)**.  Using Non-Thread Safe (NTS) did not work for me (or others), and the Thread Safe build comes bundled with the needed Apache Module for PHP "php5apache2_4.dll".  Once all my bit-depths and thread safety was matched up, Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5 work well together on my Windows systems.

Both products must also have been compiled using the same major versions of Microsoft Visual Studio/C++, such as VC6 (the legacy VC++ compiler), VC9=Studio 2008, or VC11=Studio 2012. For the above Apache versions, only VC9 or VC11 are commonly used.

**Links:**

Get Windows Apache binaries here:
**http://www.apachelounge.com/download/**

Get Windows PHP binaries here:
**http://windows.php.net/download/**

Install the Visual C++ Redistributable compiler runtime library for the specific Visual Studio version used to prepare both Apache and PHP for Windows:

2012: **http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679**

2008: **http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582**

Comment: Installing the redistributables did it for me.

Comment: The big hint here for me is that the non-thread safe version does not come with the dll. Very helpful to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Apache win 32 with 64 bits its the problem, you need Apache64

Comment: No. You can run 32 bit on 64 bit.

Comment: I think he means, if your Apache is 32bit you cannot run 64bit PHP DLL with it.