# Cannot load C:/server/php/php-8.2.13/php8apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, apache2.4, loadmodule

I am trying to install apache 2.4.58 with php 8.2.13 version. Below are steps I have done for installtion

1. Extracted apache 2.4.58 from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/
2. Extracted php 8.2.13(tar.gz) from https://www.php.net/releases/
3. In conf/httpd.conf file I have below necessary configs - 
   LoadModule php_module "C:/server/php/php-8.2.13/ext/php8apache2_4.dll"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   PHPIniDir "C:/server/php/php-8.2.13/"
4. Below is configs from php-8.2.13/php.ini file - 
   extension_dir = "C:\server\php\php-8.2.13\ext"
   extension=php8apache2_4.dll

When I run command PS `.\bin\httpd.exe -k install -n httpd` then getting below message on PowerShell.

```
PS C:\server\apache\apache-2.4.58\Apache24> .\bin\httpd.exe -k install -n httpd
Installing the 'httpd' service
The 'httpd' service is successfully installed.
Testing httpd.conf....
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 75 of C:/server/apache/apache-2.4.58/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/server/php/php-8.2.13/ext/php8apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

I also have cross checked that necessary files have full permission and are on required location on my machine.
After google a lot I did not get anything specific, so I am not able to understand what is the issue exactly or am I missing anything.
It will be highly appreciated if someone have faced and solved the same problem recently.

I have mentioned what I tried.

Comment: You're probably missing the matching version of the necessary Microsoft VC++ re-distributable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42724749/1427878

Comment: I have VC++ Redistributable 2015-2022 (x64) 14.38.33130.